# PHP/Apache - Web server not respecting RewriteRule?

Tags: php, apache, web-hosting

I have a site hosted on Hostinger and was experimenting with RewriteRule in .htaccess, and here's what I ended up using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(accounts)/[0-9]+[/]?$ /account?$2
```

I was hoping that this would redirect /accounts/[id] to /account?[id] but instead I get a 404. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I also did not mention that this is on a subdomain. Should htaccess be on the www document root and not the subdomain document root? Would be weird

Comment: You only have one capturing group.

Comment: @Siguza ^/accounts/[0-9]+$ does not seem to work either

Comment: Well no, because then you have zero. But Alberto already provided a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only capturing only one group, and pasting `$2`, therefore this wont work... instead you should do:

```
RewriteRule ^(accounts)/([0-9]+)[/]?$ /account?$2 [R=301,L]
                         ^      ^
```

But you can just capture one group:

```
RewriteRule ^accounts/([0-9]+)/?$ /account?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I didn't know the variables depended on capture groups. I updated this in my htaccess but it still does not seem to be working. RewriteEngine is processing, but not RewriteRule it seems

Comment: @WasabiThumbs my mistake, I should have pointed out that you should provide RewriteRule the policy to redirect the user

Comment: I updated my .htaccess yet again, no luck. I'm sure that you know what you are doing and that I am just missing something vital

Comment: @WasabiThumbs edited, there was an error on the REGEX, test the second one (`RewriteRule ^accounts/([0-9]+)/?$ /account?id=$1 [R=301,L]`)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! What I have learned is that PHP regex rules are very sensitive.

Comment: @WasabiThumbs yes, a ton... just to share tolls that you might be helpful, check this page https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, it will help you a ton on Htaccess management

Comment: I've been using that tool this whole time, was a good sanity check against browser caching